# Informational lane to display currently promoted version codes

Tags: fastlane

According to [the documentation of fastlane supply](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#retrieve-track-version-codes), it is possible to "provide an informational lane that displays the currently promoted version codes for the production track".

How would I concretely do that? I've seen quite a bit of documentation, but still don't understand it.

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the action [`google_play_track_version_codes`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/google_play_track_version_codes/) like this:

```
lane :output_promoted_version_codes do
  UI.message("Promoted version code (production): #{google_play_track_version_codes}")
  UI.message("Promoted version code (beta): #{google_play_track_version_codes(track: "beta")}")
end
```

When you run this lane via `fastlane android output_promoted_version_codes`, you will get output similar to this:

```
...
[10:59:02]: Driving the lane 'android output_promoted_version_codes' 
[10:59:02]: ---------------------------------------------
[10:59:02]: --- Step: google_play_track_version_codes ---
[10:59:02]: ---------------------------------------------
[10:59:06]: Found '3' version codes in track 'production'
[10:59:06]: Promoted version code (production): [3]
[10:59:06]: ---------------------------------------------
[10:59:06]: --- Step: google_play_track_version_codes ---
[10:59:06]: ---------------------------------------------
[10:59:08]: No version codes found in track 'beta'
[10:59:08]: Promoted version code (beta): []
...
```